# Spring Data REST throwing error when using JPA CriteriaQuery with joins

Tags: spring-data-jpa, spring-data-rest

When using Spring Data REST with JPA/Hibernate and exposing a spring JpaRepository via REST, I am getting an error with JPA Criteria query.  This is a Spring Boot application.

Couple of related entities:

```
@Entity
public class Appointment {  
...  
...  
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)  
@JoinColumn(name="doctor_id", insertable=false, updatable=false)  
private Doctor doctor;  
...  
...  
}  

@Entity
public class Doctor {  
...  
...  
@Column(name = "doctor_name")  
private String doctorName = "";  
...  
...  
}
```

Trying to return a list of appointments matching doctor name, I have the JPA specification built as follows:

```
public Specification<Appointment> getSpecification() {
    return new Specification<Appointment>() {

        Join<Appointment, Doctor> doctorJoin;

        @Override
        public Predicate toPredicate(Root<Appointment> root, 
                CriteriaQuery<?> query, 
                CriteriaBuilder cb) {
            Predicate p = cb.conjunction();
            ... //other critieria
            p = addDoctorCriteria(p, cb, root, Doctor_.doctorName, getDoctorName());

            return p;
        }


        private Predicate addDoctorCriteria(Predicate p,
                CriteriaBuilder cb, Root<Appointment> root, SingularAttribute<Doctor, String> property, String value) {

            value = value + '%';

            if (doctorJoin == null) {
                doctorJoin = root.join(Appointment_.doctor);
            }

            p = cb.and(p, cb.like(cb.lower(doctorJoin.<String>get(property)), value));

            return p;
        }
    };
}
```

This throws the following exception:

```
org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException:  
Invalid path: 'generatedAlias1.doctorName'  
[select count(generatedAlias0) from my.package.Appointment as generatedAlias0   
where ( 1=1 ) and ( lower(generatedAlias1.doctorName) like :param0 )];
```

Looks like the join query is not correct - there is no 'generatedAlias1' in the from clause. Seems to be happening when Spring tries to get the count of rows to build pagination information. Other criteria that depends on the attributes of Appointment (i.e. without the join) works great.

Am I doing the JPA join correctly? Any suggestions on how to correct this error?

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I got this to work, in case somebody comes across this question:

```
Root<Doctor> doctor = query.from(Doctor.class);
Predicate j1 = cb.equal(root.get(Appointment_.doctor), doctor);
Predicate c1 =  cb.like(cb.lower(doctor.<String>get(Doctor_.doctorName)), getDoctorName() + '%');
p = cb.and(p, cb.and(j1, c1));
```